# How to permanently redirect using 301 from existing ASP website to new PHP website?

Tags: php, redirect

I have a website which is currently running in legacy ASP. Now, I have redesigned the website using PHP and the website is ready. The existing hosting is windows and new website moved to Linux.

Now, I want to point the existing website https://www.example.com/news/article.asp?id=1234 to https://www.example.com/article.php?cat=1&id=1234

The id=1234 will be changing as per the news, so I want a solution which will dynamically point to the new URL. How to do this?

**I don't want to lose the page rankings and pages already indexed by Google.**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cheers
Anush

Comment: Look into IIS URL re-writing

Comment: Is the below code right?RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/article[^/]*/(.*)/([^/]*)$ article.php?cat=$1&id=$2   [L]

Comment: Well does it work against all your test cases? That's how you tell if it's right or not

Comment: My question was whether the structure is correct for the scenario I mentioned.

Comment: At a glance it looks basically fine. I'm not a frequent user of such rules so I won't comment on the exact syntax for now. You could re-tag your question with relevant tags if you want to attract the attention of people with more experience of it. In the meantime, go ahead and test in your test environment

Comment: @ADyson The rules would need to be implemented on their new server because the domain will eventually no longer point to their old server.  Since it is running Linux, probably not IIS, more likely Apache/.htaccess.

Comment: @AnushM What web server is your new site using?  Apache?   Can you give an example of an old URL with a category in it?  Your suggested rewrite rule doesn't match the example in your question.  Please [edit] your question to provide the details rather than commenting.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller that is a good point, thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, as my father passed away. The new webserver is Apache.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey Any help on this?